# reverse geocoding with python geocoder

Tags: python, python-2.7, geocoding

I'm trying my hands on reverse geocoding with python and the module geocoder

I built this script

```
#!/Users/admin/anaconda/bin/python

import geocoder
import unicodecsv
import logging


with open('locs2.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f, encoding='iso-8859-1')
    for line in reader:
        lat = line['lat']
        lon = line['lon']
        g = geocoder.google(['lat','lon'], method=reverse)
        if g.ok:
          g.postal
          logging.info('Geocoding SUCCESS: ' + address)
        else:
          logging.warning('Geocoding ERROR: ' + address)
```

According to the doc [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder/0.9.1), we can do reverse. However, when I'm running the script , I have this error `NameError: name 'reverse' is not defined`

Why?

TIA

**This is a sample from my file**

```
lat, lon
48.7082,2.2797
48.7577,2.2188
47.8333,2.2500
48.9833,1.7333
47.9333,1.9181
46.2735,4.2586
```

**Edit **: I've amended the script a bit (see below) and I have this error

```
WARNING:root:Geocoding ERROR:
```

**the amended script**

```
#!/Users/admin/anaconda/bin/python

import geocoder
import unicodecsv
import logging

pcode=[] 
lat=[]
lon=[]


with open('locs2.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = unicodecsv.DictReader(f, encoding='iso-8859-1')
    for line in reader:
        lat = line['lat']
        lon = line['lon']
        g = geocoder.google([lat,lon], method='reverse')
        if g.ok:
          pcode.extend(g.postal)
          logging.info('Geocoding SUCCESS: '+
str(lat)+','+str(lon)+','+str(pcode))
        else:
          logging.warning('Geocoding ERROR: ' + str(lat)+','+str(lon))

fields= 'lat', 'lon', 'pcode'
rows=zip(lat,lon,pcode) 

with open('/Users/admin/python/myfile.csv', 'wb') as outfile: 
    w =  unicodecsv.writer(outfile, encoding='iso-8859-1') 
    w.writerow(fields) 
    for i in rows: 
        w.writerow(i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to add quotes around your option `reverse`:

```
g = geocoder.google(['lat','lon'], method='reverse')
```

I consider that a mistake in their documentation. You could send a message to the author to inform him/her of this, he/she might want to update their docs.

Furthermore, you'll want to call it with the actual parameters `lat` and `lon`, not the strings. Otherwise you'll get an error.
So,

```
g = geocoder.google([lat, lon], method='reverse')  # lat and lon you've extracted already, but maybe you'll still need to cast them to float.
```

---

*Update: if you're running into reverse lookups that give `g.ok == False`*, then the problem is related to the throttling of your requests by the API provider (in the examples above, this is Google). For example, the [Google Maps API specifies fair use](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits) and should not be polled overly fast. This information is clear when you call `g.debug()`. Among the output will be:

```
## Provider's Attributes
* status: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
* error_message: You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API.
```

To throttle your requests, you could do the following:

```
import geocoder
import unicodecsv
import logging
import time
import csv

pcode=[]

with open('locs2.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:            
        lat = float(line['lat'])
        lon = float(line['lon'])
        g = geocoder.google([lat,lon], method='reverse')
        attempts = 1  # number of lookups
        while not(g.ok) and attempts < 4:
            logging.warning('Geocoding ERROR: {}'.format(g.debug()))
            time.sleep(2)  # 2 seconds are specified in the API. If you still get errors, it's because you've reached the daily quota.
            g = geocoder.google([lat,lon], method='reverse')
            attempts += 1
        if attempts > 3:
            logging.warning('Daily quota of google lookups exceeded.')
            break
        pcode.extend(g.postal)
        logging.info('Geocoding SUCCESS: ({},{},{})'.format(lat,lon,pcode))
```

Some of the providers, such as Mapquest, don't impose throttling at the moment.

One bug present in geocoder version 0.9.1 is that `lat`and `lon` should both differ from `0.0`. The lookup will generate a `TypeError` if you have coordinates like that (along the equator or the Greenwhich meridian).

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks for your help. I've amended a bit my script and I've got a new error. Does it ring any bell with you? TIA

Comment: @AndyK The "error" you're getting is merely a warning generated by your call to the logging module: `logging.warning('Geocoding ERROR:')`. That means that the expression `g.ok` evaluates to `False` for some particular reverse lookup. Without your source data, we cannot say why that is happening. You could use  `logging.warning('Geocoding ERROR: ({}, {})'.format(lat, lon))` to know for which coordinates it fails.

Comment: Oliver, I just realized. Damn , I feel terriby unfamiliar with Python yet !!!

This is my source file.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/srb8skg7lysnj95/locs2.csv?dl=0

Would you mind helping me a bit, please?

Comment: I've amended my script again (see the post). I can see that I got geocoding error for the 9th line with `45.8167,5.9167`.

Bizarre thing is the successes are not shown...

Comment: A reverse lookup on those coordinates works for me: `g.ok` evaluates to `True`. We should move this discussion to [chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57537/how-do-i-contact-other-users) if you want to debug it.

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a moment, please join me [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18647/reverse-geocoding-with-python-geocoder-debugging)

Comment: Wait. it seems I need to login -_-

Comment: Hi Oliver, almost there. The sucesses are not displayed at my end.

Comment: Please find the errors `
I've got these errors `Debug
## Connection
* URL: [Reverse](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json)
* Status: ERROR - URL Connection
* Status Code: 404
* Parameter [latlng]: 44.8325,-0.6338
* Parameter [sensor]: false

## JSON Attributes
* status: ERROR - URL Connection
* provider: reverse
* location: [44.8325, -0.6338]
* error: ERROR - URL Connection
`

Comment: One more thing: Please have in mind I need the post code. I'm reverse geocoding only for that reason otherwise, this exercise would be pointless for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64946/discussion-between-oliver-w-and-andy-k).

Comment: Hi Oliver, quick update: After many attempts with that reverse geocoding , I was able with the help of the author of the reverse geocoding package to get all the reverse geocoding I was looking for. He created the package for reverse geocoding for mapquest, which does not have throttling.I'm updating a bit the script to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

Geocoder has come a long way, the recent version is 1.6.1 which has hopefully fixed a few bugs you are mentioning.

Check out the latest documentation for [Reverse Geocoding in Python Geocoder](http://geocoder.readthedocs.org/api.html#reverse-geocoding).

```
import geocoder

g = geocoder.google([45.15, -75.14], method='reverse')
g.city
g.state
g.country
g.postal
```

Here are the list of providers that support reverse geocoding:

- [Bing](http://geocoder.readthedocs.org/providers/Bing.html)
- [Google](http://geocoder.readthedocs.org/providers/Google.html)
- [Mapbox](http://geocoder.readthedocs.org/providers/Mapbox.html)
- [MapQuest](http://geocoder.readthedocs.org/providers/MapQuest.html)
- [What3Words](http://geocoder.readthedocs.org/providers/What3Words.html)
- [HERE](http://geocoder.readthedocs.org/providers/HERE.html)
- [Yandex](http://geocoder.readthedocs.org/providers/Yandex.html)